# PDB file is not paired with exe and source code

Tags: c#, debugging, roslyn, pdb-files

I used [CSharpCompilation.Emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpfilesystemextensions.emit?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0) function to create exe and pdb from my .cs script.

```
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(SourceText.From(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Temp\\Z\\Simple.cs")));

        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Simple.exe")
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication))
            .AddReferences(
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox).Assembly.Location)
            )
            .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit("C:\\Temp\\Z\\Simple.exe", "C:\\Temp\\Z\\Simple.pdb");
```

However when I try to use it in debugger, the pdb module is not correctly recognized. It's not paired with my Simple.exe and Simple.cs files. If I attach to running process , it goes to another instance of Simple.exe without pdb loaded. What could I do to fix it?

*Update: I noticed following information in Modules window:*

> This module is a pre-compiled binary created by the ngen.exe tool. The debugger does not attempt to load symbols for these binaries, but will instead load symbols for original dll/exe when it is loaded by the .NET Runtime.

[image: List of modules]

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.text.sourcetext.from?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Text_SourceText_From_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Text_SourceHashAlgorithm_) specifically warn about this.  Quote: "If the encoding is not specified the resulting SourceText isn't debuggable."

Comment: @HansPassant I tried to specify encoding, it didn't help. Based on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8281 I see possibility that it is implemented in .NET Core, but not in .NET Framework 4.8.